# How to subtract a value from 2 text field and store the value in second text field?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, wpf, operators

I am having a project in which I have a fields like price, quantity, total amount , paid amount, pending amount & credit amount paid. Now the calculation for total amount is been done by using multiply operator. Now when a user enters paid amount this calculation happens that is: Total Amount- Paid Amount = Pending Amount.

Suppose the Total amount is 40 and paid amount is 20 so pending will be 20. After some days the remaining credit amount is credited so it will be 20 so the calculation I was Trying now is Pending Amount - Credit Amount = Pending Amount. So the final amount should be 0. Below is Screenshot of front end:

[image]

I tried the following code from my side but the pending amount field is not getting to 0 or the amount remaining.Below is my code :

```
    private void Price_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Multiply();
    }
    private void Quantity_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Multiply();
    }
    public void Multiply()
    {
        int a, b;
        bool isAValid = int.TryParse(txtprice.Text, out a);
        bool isBValid = int.TryParse(txtquantity.Text, out b);
        if (isAValid && isBValid)
        {
            txttotalamount.Text = (a * b).ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            txttotalamount.Text = "Invalid Input";
        }
    }

    private void TotalAmount_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Subtract();
    }

    private void PaidAmount_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Subtract();
    }
    private void PendingAmount_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Subtract();
    }

    private void txtcreditamountpaid_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Subtract();
    }
    public void Subtract()
    {
        int a, b,c,d;
        bool isAValid = int.TryParse(txttotalamount.Text, out a);
        bool isBValid = int.TryParse(txtpaidamount.Text, out b);
        bool isCValid = int.TryParse(txtpendingamount.Text,out c);
        bool isDValid = int.TryParse(txtcreditamountpaid.Text, out d);
        if (isAValid && isBValid)
        {
            string e = (a - b).ToString();
            txtpendingamount.Text = (e).ToString();
        }
        else if (isCValid && isDValid)
        {
            string f=(c-d).ToString();
            txtpendingamount.Text = (f).ToString();
        }  
        else
        {
            txtpendingamount.Text = "invalid Input";
        }
    }

}
```

I expect the output in pending amount field to be 0 or the remaining amount that is been entered in credit amount field. I tried from myself however its not working!

Comment: "...notworking..." - this information is not really helpful. It does not say what exactly did not work, i.e. did you get any error messages anywhere, did you try to debug the issue to make sure that it actually does the intended thing.

Comment: looks like a someones homework to me:\ Have you try to debug?

Comment: That is problem I m not getting an exception or error I tried debugging my program the flow is proper but my question is what i need to do so i can get nil or remaining amount in pending amount field after credit amount is been entered @JohnB

Comment: John is asking what `its not working!` means. What happens when you enter a value in `txtcreditamountpaid` value? What is outputed in `txtpendingamount`?

Comment: I have posted a screenshot above.... No calculation is done when creditamount is entered the amount remains the same in pending amount @vasily.sib

Comment: and you have checked, that your `Subtract()` method is invoking (breakpoint is hit) when you enter a value in `txtcreditamountpaid`?

Comment: Are the `Price_TextChanged` and `Quantity_TextChanged` bound?

Comment: Sorry I m jst a begineer and I dont have much idea about it @vasily.sib

Comment: I have used them for multiplication and show them in total amount @CodePope

Comment: I know @RaoRajnish you are using them for multiplication, but they have to be bound to the `TextChanged` event of the control, otherwise they are not called. So are they handled by the control?

Comment: Yes they are bounded @CodePope

Comment: set a breakpoint at the begining of `Subtract()` debug your app and see if it hit this breakpoint. If no - you not bound `TextChanged` of `txtcreditamountpaid` event to `txtcreditamountpaid_TextChanged` handler.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void txtcreditamountpaid_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Subtract(true);
    }
    public void Subtract(bool isCreditAmount = false)
    {
        int a, b,c,d;
        bool isAValid = int.TryParse(txttotalamount.Text, out a);
        bool isBValid = int.TryParse(txtpaidamount.Text, out b);
        bool isCValid = int.TryParse(txtpendingamount.Text,out c);
        bool isDValid = int.TryParse(txtcreditamountpaid.Text, out d);
        if (isAValid && isBValid && !isCreditAmount)
        {
            string e = (a - b).ToString();
            txtpendingamount.Text = (e).ToString();
        }
        else if (isCValid && isDValid)
        {
            string f=(c-d).ToString();
            txtpendingamount.Text = (f).ToString();
        }  
        else
        {
            txtpendingamount.Text = "invalid Input";
        }
    }
```

Change your code like this. It will work.

Comment: Sorry but i Tried this but still not working :( ! @ganeshkumar

Comment: No @RaoRajnish. It must be work. Check your code. You have to modify these lines only. 

Subtract(true);

public void Subtract(bool isCreditAmount = false) and

if (isAValid && isBValid && !isCreditAmount)

Once you enter credit amout and leave from that field, then it will work. Please check again.

Comment: Sorry but i Just made changes and also I just copied and paste your code and replaced my code @ganeshkumar

Answer (score 0):

Try following code for Subtract Method:

```
public void Subtract()
    {
        int a, b,c,d;
        bool isAValid = int.TryParse(txttotalamount.Text, out a);
        bool isBValid = int.TryParse(txtpaidamount.Text, out b);

        if (isAValid && isBValid)
        {
            string e = (a - b).ToString();
            txtpendingamount.Text = (e).ToString();
        }

 bool isCValid = int.TryParse(txtpendingamount.Text,out c);
        bool isDValid = int.TryParse(txtcreditamountpaid.Text, out d);

        if (isCValid && isDValid)
        {
            string f=(c-d).ToString();
            txtpendingamount.Text = (f).ToString();
        }  
        else
        {
            txtpendingamount.Text = "invalid Input";
        }
    }
```